# node/express pausing before a redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.post("/remove", function(req,res){
  let jobs = fetchJobs();
  jobs.splice(req.body.prodId,1);
  fs.writeFileSync("jobs.json", JSON.stringify(jobs));
    //some sort of pause here
  res.redirect("/list");
})
```

I use this code to delete an Item from an array. The /list site just loops throught the array and prints every item, however after executing this code I have to refresh my page before the change is shown. Is there any other way to redirect to my page or to add a tiny pause before res.redirect("/list"); so that my json file has enough time to update?

Comment: Your JSON is updated before the redirect (as you're using the `Sync` version of `writeFile`). are you sure this is the problem?

Comment: Have you checked your`fetchJobs()` function? Like @nadavvadan pointed out the redirect happens after the writing to the file

Comment: yeah, my fetchJobs() function just parses the files: `return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("jobs.json"))`

Comment: `jobs.splice(req.body.prodId,1);`  is `prodId` correct?, splice takes an index into the array, so `prodid` doesn't really seem correct.

Comment: prodId is the index of the item that I want to delete. I passed it in earlier in a hidden input `<input id="prodId" name="prodId" type="hidden" value=<%= i %>>` I just kept the name because I'm lazy and copy pasted it from mdn. Everything in the code works as it should.

Comment: I'm fairly new to node, but node is supposed to be non-blocking right? So it makes sense that the redirect executes while my json is still being written, at least that's the only theory I could come up with

Comment: @cubefox One issue is that if you get multiple POST requests `fs.writeFileSync` is trying to write to the same file more than once simuntaniously which is really bad and when there is a GET request to `/list` which requires your file to be read happening at the same time then you are trying to read and write to the same file all at once.

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann thanks for the Input, right now there is only one admin who is able to delete Items but I'll keep that in mind when I add an actual database (and not just a json file). The simultaneous reading/writing is a problem that's why for now I wanted to add a pause inbetween, but I don't really know how to do that...

Comment: Use the async method of writeFile and in the callback execute the redirect.

Comment: It's a bit old, but in case it helps someone, the problem may come from nodemon. run your app with node and check

Comment: or execute: nodemon index.js --ignore /path/save-files